# ios: UIImageView Resizes when setImage called

Tags: ios, uiimageview, image-resizing

When I call setImage the UIImageView resizes:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil title:(NSString *)t distance:(NSString *)d image:(UIImage *)i{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        name = [t retain];
        distance = [d retain];
        image = [i retain];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [marketImage setImage:image];
}
```

If the image is larger than the UIImageView the UIImageView resizes. I did not call sizeToFit so I dont know why this would happen. Any reason why I encounter a resize?

Should I uncheck autoresize subviews?

Comment: how do you initialize the UIImageView?

Comment: It's not resizing, it's most probably because of the content mode.

Comment: @Desdenova No it does resize and I dont want it to resize.

Comment: I set the image in IB for the default. then I call setImage.

Comment: From docs: `Setting the image property does not change the size of a UIImageView.`

Comment: @Desdenova Yes, but I also have autoresize subviews checked. This might be the problem.

Comment: What is the content mode of the UIImageView? I'd put money on it being "center" or "UIViewContentModeCenter". Also, that you don't have "clips sub views" ticked. Am I right?

Comment: What's the content mode of the `UIImageView`? did you `NSLog` the frame after you set the image?

Comment: @Desdenova current mode is scale to fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

In IB if you set the image with a picture that you imported, then you call

```
[image setImage:newImage]
```

IOS will resize the UIImageView, but if instead you leave the image empty in IB then it will not resize.